# Expand Recyclerview on Search

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I nearly achieved what I wanted but 1 thing is still missing. I have a recyclerview and each item has it's own recyclerview. But in the beginning, every item's own recyclerview isn't shown. It expands as soon as you press the button.

But I also want to expand it, when I start filtering the recyclerview using the Searchbar.

That's my Adapter:

```
public class SchrankAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SchrankAdapter.ViewHolder> implements Filterable {

private Context context;
ArrayList<CategoryName> categoryTopic = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<CategoryName> categoryTopicFull;


public SchrankAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<CategoryName> categoryTopic){

    this.context = context;
    this.categoryTopic = categoryTopic;
    categoryTopicFull = new ArrayList<>(categoryTopic);

}


@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_schrank, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    CategoryName parentItem = categoryTopic.get(position);
    holder.categoryName.setText(parentItem.categoryName);



    setCatItemRecycler(holder.childRecView, categoryTopic.get(position).getChildViewList());


    holder.btFolderPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holder.btFolderMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btFolderPlus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    });

    holder.btFolderMinus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            holder.btFolderPlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.btFolderMinus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });


}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return categoryTopic.size();
}

private void setCatItemRecycler(RecyclerView recyclerView, ArrayList<CategoryChild> categoryChildrenList) {

    SchrankChildAdapter childAdapter = new SchrankChildAdapter(context, categoryChildrenList);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(childAdapter);
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return filter;
}

private Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        ArrayList<CategoryName> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<CategoryChild> filteredSubList = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean containsSubItems = false;

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

            filteredList.addAll(categoryTopicFull);

        } else {
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (CategoryName item: categoryTopicFull) {

                for(CategoryChild subItem: item.getChildViewList()) {

                    if(subItem.getCategoryAttribute().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredSubList.add(subItem);
                        containsSubItems = true;
                    }
                }

                if(containsSubItems) {
                    filteredList.add(new CategoryName(item.getCategoryName(), filteredSubList));
                    containsSubItems = false;
                    filteredSubList = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            }


        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
        categoryTopic.clear();
        categoryTopic.addAll((ArrayList) results.values);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    TextView categoryName;
    RelativeLayout childView;
    RecyclerView childRecView;
    Button btFolderPlus, btFolderMinus;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        categoryName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
        childView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.childView);
        childRecView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.childRecView);
        btFolderPlus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btFolderPlus);
        btFolderMinus = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btFolderMinus);
    }
}
```

}

That's my SearchView in the activity:

```
SearchView searchView = findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            schrankAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The variable ***childView*** is responsible for the subItems. I want to set it's Visibility to VISIBLE whenever I enter something in the searchbar.

It's all working, I just want to improve my current program.

***UPDATE:***
Ok, I found a solution for my problem.
I created a boolean which is set to false from the beginning.

I added this code to ***onBindViewHolder*** method:

```
if(isSearching) {

        holder.btFolderMinus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.childView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btFolderPlus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else if(!isSearching) {

        holder.btFolderPlus.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.btFolderMinus.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        holder.childView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

And I edited my ***Filter:***

```
private Filter filter = new Filter() {
    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
        ArrayList<CategoryName> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<CategoryChild> filteredSubList = new ArrayList<>();
        boolean containsSubItems = false;

        if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

            filteredList.addAll(categoryTopicFull);
            isSearching = false;

        } else {
            String filterPattern = constraint.toString().toLowerCase().trim();

            for (CategoryName item: categoryTopicFull) {

                for(CategoryChild subItem: item.getChildViewList()) {

                    if(subItem.getCategoryAttribute().toLowerCase().contains(filterPattern)) {
                        filteredSubList.add(subItem);
                        containsSubItems = true;
                    }
                }

                if(containsSubItems) {
                    filteredList.add(new CategoryName(item.getCategoryName(), filteredSubList));
                    containsSubItems = false;
                    filteredSubList = new ArrayList<>();
                }
            }

            isSearching = true;
        }

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        results.values = filteredList;

        return results;
    }
```

Maybe someone will search for this solution one-day.